# Angular2 Componenet not rendering only on refresh

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 admin application,after i login successfully i'm redirected to the dashboard (`DashboardComponenent`) which is rendering only when i refresh the page. i tried several methods to fix the problem but nothing worked.

i believe that my problem comes from `App.componenet.html`

```
  <div *ngIf=" title!='login' && title!='signup'&& title!='forgot'&& title!='forgotpass'"  class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-background-color="white" data-active-color="danger">
        <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <navbar-cmp></navbar-cmp>
        <div class="content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        </div>
        <footer-cmp></footer-cmp>
    </div> 
<!--    <fixedplugin-cmp></fixedplugin-cmp> -->

 </div>
<div *ngIf="title=='login' " class="wrapper">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="title=='signup' " class="wrapper">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="title=='forgot' " class="wrapper">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="title=='forgotpass' " class="wrapper">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Any idea about the cause of this problem?

Comment: why are you using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` multiple times?

Comment: As Nikhil said, you should only have the `router-outlet` tag once in your page. Instead of using ngif to conditionally show different components you should be using actual routes - https://angular.io/guide/router.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your **app.module.ts** as below.
>

> `const appRoutes: Routes = [
>
>    { path: 'login', component:YourLoginComponent },
>
>    { path: 'signup', component:YourSignupComponent }, 
>    { path: 'forgot', component:YourForgotComponent },
>    { path: 'forgotpass',  component:YourForgotPassComponent },
>    { path: '',
>          redirectTo: '/login', // in case no path provided
>          pathMatch: 'full'   } 
>    ];`
>
> `@NgModule({   imports: [
>                    RouterModule.forRoot(
>                        appRoutes,
>                    { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
>       )
>       // other imports here   ],
>   ... }) 
>      export class AppModule { }`

and then in **app.component.html** you can have:

> `<nav>
>       <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
>       <a routerLink="/signup">Sign Up</a>
>       <a routerLink="/forgot">Forgot</a>
>       <a routerLink="/forgotpass">Forgot Pass</a>
>   </nav> 
>   <router-outlet></router-outlet>`

So what happens here is the **nav** in **app.component.html** acts as
the remote control to switch the channels. The instruction about the
working process of the remote control is defined in the *appRoutes*
under **app.module.ts**. And the 
acts as the Television screen where we see the selected channel. So
Basically in your case there is no use of multiple router outlets.

for deeper understanding you can go through
https://angular.io/guide/router